# Run shell and check port of specific postgresql version in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shell, postgresql, psql

Several versions of postgresql (9.3, 9.4 and 9.5) on a server with different ports and I want to start the shell of a specific one. If I run the shell:

```
psql
```

It returns:

```
psql (9.5.0, server 9.3.10)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

I think that I just started 9.5, so until now; well done.
However, when I check the version with:

```
select version();
```

It returns:

```
version
PostgreSQL 9.3.10 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu,
compiled by gcc (Ubuntu     4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit
```

Confusing; My server is version 9.3? But it runs 9.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 9.5 is the version of the `psql` tool you are using. It get's updated at each installation of a new PostgreSQL.
- 9.3 is the version of the DBMS you are currently connected to.

When running just `psql` it connects to the default port 5432 so I'm guessing the 9.3 version of PostgreSQL is on that port. Try with `psql --port=X` and set `X` to a port of different PostgreSQL daemon; you should see different versions then.